# ConversionServiceFactoryBean Does Not Work

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I'm working with a special CacheConfig object that holds a field (with standard getter/setter methods), `accessExpirationValue`, which is of type `java.time.Duration`.  (**EDIT:** actually, the field is of type Long (the number of seconds), but the getter and setter are of type Duration.)

I'm trying to wire this in Spring by setting this value as a number of seconds and using a ConversionServiceFactoryBean, like so:

Relevant beans in ApplicationContext.xml:

```xml
<bean id="conversionService"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean" >
  <property name="converters">
    <set>
      <bean
          class="com.tjamesboone.example.config.SecondsToDurationConverter"/>
    </set>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheConfig" class="com.tjamesboone.example.cache.CacheConfig" >
  <property name="accessExpirationValue" value="0" />
</bean>
```

SecondsToDurationConverter:

```java
package com.tjamesboone.example.cache;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class SecondsToDurationConverter implements Converter<String, Duration> {

  @Override
  public Duration convert(String seconds) {
    return Duration.ofSeconds(Long.parseLong(seconds));
  }

}
```

Now, as I understand it, this is supposed to ***just work***.  When I pass in "0" for the value of `accessExpirationValue`, the fact that I've declared a conversionService bean that handles converting Strings to Durations means that is should set the value as a Duration of zero length.

But this would be to easy.  And it is.  Because when I test my application (using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner), I get this error, ***as if I'd never registered a Converter***:

> Bean property 'accessExpirationValue' is not writable or has an
>   invalid setter method.  Does the parameter type of the setter match
>   the return type of the getter?

So my question is, *What am I doing wrong?*  How do I get this to work they way I want?

For reference, this is the primary documentation I've been using:
**https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert-Spring-config**

It specifically says,

> In a Spring application, you typically configure a ConversionService instance per Spring container (or ApplicationContext). That ConversionService will be picked up by Spring and then used whenever a type conversion needs to be performed by the framework.

**EDIT:**
I should probably also post the relevant part of CacheConfig!

```java
package com.tjamesboone.example.config;

import java.time.Duration;

public class CacheConfig {

  private Long accessExpirationValue;

  public Duration getAccessExpiration() {
    return Duration.ofSeconds(accessExpirationValue.intValue);
  }

  public void setAccessExpiration() {
    this.accessExpirationValue = expirationDuration.getSeconds();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring is going to try to match the properties in your bean with the getters and setters specified in your class.

Your getters/setters are currently getAccessExpiration() but should be getAccessExpirationValue() to match your bean property name="accessExpirationValue".  Change one or the other and you should have it.

Comment: Wow!!!!  I can't believe I missed that!  I think the reason the class (which isn't my own) has "Value" appended to the field name is because it's a different type than the API getter and setter.  I updated the ApplicationContext and now it **WORKS LIKE A CHARM!!!!**  Thanks for being a second pair of eyes, Hayes!